# How to calculate employee in time out time from two different days PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I determine the time in and time out of that employee on a particular date but employee worked on `01-01-2019 11.00` PM to `02-01-2019 07.00 AM`. How can I calculate in out time for `01-01-2019`

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: `01-01-2019 11.00 PM` is in a `timein` column of datetime and `02-01-2019 07.00 AM` is in a `timeout` column of datetime? I think times are stored in 24h format in mysql. We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: right it will be 24 hour.i posted an example.

Comment: $time_in->diffInHours($time_out);

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below mysql query

`SELECT sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(time_out, time_in)))),user_id FROM test.time group by user_id;`

This is my table

```
user_id    time_in                   time_out
   1       2019-03-05 05:30:51        2019-03-05 05:45:51
   1       2019-03-05 05:50:51        2019-03-05 05:55:51
```

Comment: you can add the condition based on your requirement, like last 24hrs, last two dates, etc